# _Query_perf_counter and QueryPerformanceCounter in Windows

Tags: c++, performance, time

Question from a C++ learner.

In Windows, using MSVC, `std::chrono::steady_clock` internally uses `_Query_perf_counter`.
And `QueryPerformanceCounter` is only for x86, I guess. (MSDN [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancecounter))

Assuming a code for x86 program (running on x64 system), 
Is there any difference between `_Query_perf_counter` and `QueryPerformanceCounter`, other than one returns `long long` and the other uses the `LARGE_INTEGER` struct?

Otherwise, any relevant references would be very helpful. Thank you!

<sub>Context: I'm writing an x86 MFC app that will run on a Windows x64 system. I'm trying to achieve the highest precision time possible.</sub>

Comment: `QueryPerformanceFrequency` and `QueryPerformanceCounter` work fine in x86 and x64. Digging into the internal details of the standard library isn't usually a good idea. They may map to the same call or they may not and there may be a good reason or not. It's an implementation detail and as long as the public facing API does what it says it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Why not just use `steady_clock`?

Comment: I question the need for still using MFC as user interface technology, but you probably have your (legacy) reasons. And it shouldn't matter your performance critical code should be developed in a C++ (static) library and its performance should be measured from tests (not from within the MFC app). Just curious why do you need high performance in your MFC app? If it is to keep the app resonponsive you shouldn't be doing work on the main thread anyway.

Comment: @AlanBirtles You're right, I just tried to dig into this as a learner and out of curiosity.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Could you advise how I can use them? If I use Visual Studio 2022(which doesn't support building x86 app), I can't use QueryPerformanceFrequency/Counter, there's some error at <profileapi.h> I think. Anyway, I think you're right, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I agree with what you said about MFC. I'm building a financial application and it uses a 3rd-party ActiveX control to interact with the server, that's why I had to use MFC. And the user interface or app responsiveness is not that important. However, I need to know exactly when each of the massively received events arrived. That's why I want the highest precision for recording timestamps. Any advice would be of great help :) Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps MFC is interfering somehow. Hard to say without seeing the code and the errors. Are you measuring relative time or do you need something that correlates to actual clock time? I ask because you mentioned timestamps. If you need actual clock times then these QPC/QPF aren't what you should be using.

Comment: crt/src/stl/xtime.cpp, _Query_perf_counter() simply calls QueryPerformanceCounter().  Probably to hide the LARGE_INTEGER implementation detail.  Do be explicit about what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you so much, the code helped me a lot! Can I ask you some questions? 1) how can I find the implementation(cpp file) like you did? 2) Problem I want to solve: I'm building a financial app that receives tons of events per second and each event needs to be timestamped. Their order must be guaranteed. (continued in next comment)

Comment: @HansPassant (continued) The solution I am thinking of: Call `_Xtime_get_ticks` and `_Query_perf_counter` at the start of the program to record the timestamp(let's call it `ts1`) and CPU ticks(`c1`), and then call QPC when each event is received to record CPU ticks(`c2`). Then add the difference of the tick counts (`c2`-`c1`) to the timestamp(`ts1`) to get the timestamp for each event. I think this will guarantee the order of each timestamp. Could you please give me any advice for my solution? (Please let me know if this better be posted as another question.)